# Problema con manipulación datos .csv en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Necesito añadir datos en distintas columnas de un archivo csv para que quede algo tipo:

(col.1)TIEMPO    (col.2)DATOS

Por ahora intento crear el archivo con las dos cabeceras de 'TIEMPO' y 'DATOS' pero tras crear el archivo, me escribe las cabeceras en distintas filas intercalando las letras de los dos strings y dejando una fila vacía entre medio.

```
import itertools
import csv
global pathname #ubicación del archivo.

l=[['TIEMPO','DATOS']]  
with open(pathname, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(itertools.izip(*l))
    f.close()
```

Trabajo con Python 2.7

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Toni, ¿el csv debería tener una primera fila (cabecera) tal que `TIEMPO,DATOS` y el resto de las filas algo así:`15,abc`? ¿Podrías agregar tu lista real con algunos datos y no solo la cabecera ?. ¿Tu lista con los datos es algo así: `l = [['TIEMPO','DATOS'], ["t1", "dato1" ], ["t2", "dato2" ], ...]` ?

Comment: Exacto, el resultado que quiero obtener es debajo de  'TIEMPO' tener  't1','t2' en distintas filas y en la siguiente columna lo mismo con los datos. No he añadido los datos por que lo hago des de otro fichero y he supuesto que se haría igual que las cabeceras de cada columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- La palabra reservada `global` se usa dentro de una función para indicar que se debe usar la variable global con ese nombre, no crear una dentro de la función. Incluso si tu código está dentro de una función, a no ser que esa función **modifique** la variable `pathname`  no es necesaria.
- Cuando usas `with` no tienes que cerrar el fichero de forma explícita, de eso precisamente (entre otras cosas) se encarga el manejador de contexto.
- `csv.writer.writerows` recibe un iterable en el que cada item es otro iterable con el contenido de cada fila. No necesitas ni desempaquetar la lista ni usar `zip`/`itertools.izip`, simplemente pásale tu lista.
- Python 2.x en principio abre siempre el fichero en modo binario cuando uses el módulo csv.

El código puede quedar así:

```
import csv

pathname = "data.csv"

datos = [['TIEMPO','DATOS'], [0, 14.20], [2, 8.25], [5, 8.14]]
with open(pathname, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(datos)
```

O si tus datos están en otro iterable sin la cabecera puedes hacer:

```
import csv

pathname = "data.csv"

datos = [[0, 14.20], [2, 8.25], [5, 8.14]]
with open(pathname, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(("TIEMPO", "DATOS"))
    writer.writerows(datos)
```

El csv resultante para el ejemplo será:

> TIEMPO,DATOS
>   0,14.2
>   2,8.25
>   5,8.14

Comment: Me lo sigue creando en una misma columna. Me guarda en una misma celda 'TIEMPO' y 'DATO' y en distintas celdas de la misma columna los datos.
Podría ser algún problema de compatibilidad con Excel al abrir el archivo? Utilizo Excel 2013.

Comment: ¿Si abres el archivo csv en un editor de texto tiene la estructura correcta? No tengo a mano Excel ni lo suelo usar mucho pero el código que pongo genera un csv correcto, en LibreOffice se abre sin problemas y el separador que usas es el estándar para un csv....

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, era un problema con excel. El código funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias.